# Angular HttpClient post method parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't understand the following type in typescript. An example of the obj value would be really helpful.

```
 obj: { [name: string]: string | string[]; };
```

I am actually trying to understand the type of the  headers property of the options object in the post method of the HttpClient in Angular:

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    ...
    }
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: It's an object whose property names are strings and whose property values are either strings or arrays of strings: `{ 'foo': 'bar', 'baz': ['qux'] }`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break it up step by step with the following Typescript rules

a type defenition with vertical bars between type defenitions is called a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) this means it can be any of the defined types.

```
let foo: string | number = 0; // foo must be a string or a number
foo = "a string";
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20foo%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%3D%200%3B%20%2F%2F%20foo%20must%20be%20a%20string%20or%20a%20number%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20%22a%20string%22%3B)

return types can be object. In this case you define the key by typing the name of the key and the type.

```
const obj: {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
} = {foo: "a string", bar: 42 }

const err: {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
} = {foo: "a string", bar: "another string" } // this would not work, because we defined bar as a number
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20obj%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%2042%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20err%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22another%20string%22%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20this%20would%20not%20work%2C%20because%20we%20defined%20bar%20as%20a%20number)

we van also use union types to define the type

```
let obj: {
    foo: string,
    bar: number | string
} = {foo: "a string", bar: "another string" } // this works because bar can be a number OR a string
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20%20%20let%20obj%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22another%20string%22%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20this%20works%20because%20bar%20can%20be%20a%20number%20OR%20a%20string)

the question mark after an object key will tell it is optional.

```
const foo: {
    foo?: string
} = {} // is valid

const bar: {
    foo?: string
} = { foo: "a string" } // is also valid

const baz: {
    foo?: string
} = {bar: "a string"} // invalid because bar is no property of type {foo?: string}
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20is%20valid%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20is%20also%20valid%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20baz%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7Bbar%3A%20%22a%20string%22%7D%20%2F%2F%20invalid%20because%20bar%20is%20no%20property%20of%20type%20%7Bfoo%3F%3A%20string%7D%0D%0A)

the `{[key: string]:  string}` type says that any key is allowed as long as it can be cast to a string,

```
const foo: {
    [key: string]: string
} = {foo:"a string", bar: "another string", baz: "yet another string"} // is all valid
```

in the example written above every key is valid as long as the type is string.

```
const bar: {
    [key: string]: string
} = {foo:"a string", bar: "another string", baz: 42} // is invalid baz is not of type string
```

in this example the object is invalid because baz is not of type `string`

union types will also work

```
const baz: {
    [key: string]: string | number
} = {foo:"a string", bar: "another string", baz: 42} // is valid
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22another%20string%22%2C%20baz%3A%20%22yet%20another%20string%22%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20is%20all%20valid%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22another%20string%22%2C%20baz%3A%2042%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20is%20invalid%20baz%20is%20not%20of%20type%20string%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20baz%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%22a%20string%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22another%20string%22%2C%20baz%3A%2042%7D%20%2F%2F%20is%20valid)

so based on the rules above we can break down this method

the method is called post and it takes three arguments:

1. **url** - this is of type `string` (in this method it is the url to make the POST call to)
2. **body** - this is of type `any` **OR** of type `null` (in this method it is the body for the post call)
3. **options**: this one might look confusing, so lets break it down:

options needs to be an `object` which has an optional key named headers (it is optionals because it ends with a question mark). The key must be named headers and can not be named something else. Other keys and values can not be inserted!

`headers` must be of type HttpHeaders (a class made by angular) **OR** an **`object` where the key can be casted to a string** Since almost everything can be casted to a string almost everything can be the key. the value must be a string or an array of strings.

I hope this could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can key-value pairs on the headers property, the key would be a property name, and the value of course the value of said property, for example:

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'authToken'
    })
```

These would be the headers that are sent with the request which you can inspect on the Network tab on your browser's dev tools

Answer (score 0):

1. `options` is an object
2. It has an optional property named `headers`
3. Headers are of type `HttpHeaders` or
4. multiple properties whose keys must conform to [Index Signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) which in this case must be a `string`
5. And the values of those properties must be `string` or array of `string`s

Just saw that @jonrsharpe said the same in his comment below the question, i will remove my answer if he posts one